# Function Parameter causes segmentation fault in GMP

Tags: parameters, segmentation-fault, gmp

I am trying to change the value of d which is of type mpz_t in the function extended_gcd and then pass it back to my main function and I get a segmentation fault when I execute the program.

```
    int extended_gcd(mpz_t c, mpz_t a, mpz_t b)
    {

      mpz_t x, lastx, y, lasty, temp, quotient, temp2;

      mpz_init(temp); 
      mpz_init(temp2); 
      mpz_init(a);
      mpz_init(b);
      mpz_init(c);
      mpz_init(quotient); 
      mpz_init_set_ui(x,0); 
      mpz_init_set_ui(lastx,1);
      mpz_init_set_ui(lasty,0);
      mpz_init_set_ui(y,1);

while(!(mpz_cmp(b, 0)==0))
{
    mpz_set(temp, b);
    mpz_cdiv_q(quotient, a, b);
    mpz_mod(b, a, b);
mpz_set(a, temp);
    mpz_set(temp, x);
mpz_mul(temp2, quotient, x);
mpz_sub(x, lastx, temp2);
    mpz_set(lastx, temp);
    mpz_set(temp, y);
    mpz_mul(temp2, quotient, y);
mpz_sub(y, lasty, temp2);
    mpz_set(lasty, temp);                 
}

mpz_set(c, lastx);        
mpz_clear(x);
mpz_clear(y);
mpz_clear(lastx);
mpz_clear(lasty);
mpz_clear(temp);
mpz_clear(temp2);
mpz_clear(quotient);
 return 0;
```

}

And this is the code in my main:

```
    extended_gcd(d,e,phi);  
    printf("d=");
    mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, d);
    printf("\n");
```

Any idea what  might be wrong and how can I fix it?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I see one issue: you shouldn't call mpz_init() on the arguments to extended_gcd(). You should only call mpz_init()/mpz_clear() on the mpz_t variables declared inside extended_gcd().